# jquery multilevel accordion operation

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have to display the multilevel accordion, javascript code for this is:

```
$('#menu li a').click(
        function() {        
            var openMe = $(this).next();
            var mySiblings = $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul');
            if (openMe.is(':visible')) {                                

                openMe.slideUp("slow"); 

            } else {

                mySiblings.slideUp("slow"); 
                openMe.slideDown("slow");
            }
          }
    );
```

HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="first"><span class="level-1 bdr-radius-top">
                    <span class="column-1"><span  class="closespan">&nbsp;</span><h3>europe</h3></span>
                    <span class="column-2"><span>9</span>pays </span>
                    <span class="column-3"><span>48</span>destinations </span>
                </span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" class="first">
                        <span class="level-2">
                            <span class="column-1"><span class="closespan">&nbsp;</span><h3>&eacute;tats-unis</h3></span>
                            <span class="column-2"> &nbsp; </span>
                            <span class="column-3"> <span>7</span>destinations </span>
                        </span></a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">
                                <div  class="level-3">
                                    <div class="column-1"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                    <div class="column-2"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                </div></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">
                                <div  class="level-3">
                                    <div class="column-1"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                    <div class="column-2"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                </div></a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">
                                <div  class="level-3">
                                    <div class="column-1"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                    <div class="column-2"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">
                                <div  class="level-3">
                                    <div class="column-1"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                    <div class="column-2"> Nice - Strasbourg </div>
                                </div></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

But unfortunately, when accordion is slidingUp and slidinDown the whole html code is vibrating.
So please anyone can help me to sort out this?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `whole html code is vibrating`. I just fiddled it out and in there i see  everything working perfectly as it should be . : http://jsfiddle.net/kU4uq/